# VBA help: Opening a workbook file that changes the name daily (i.e. Sales 6.20 on monday to Sales 6.21 on Tuesday, and so on)

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a macro to open 3 workbooks: Products.xlsx, Labels.xlsx, and Sales 6.20.xlsb (the date changes daily because new information is added every day). I want to copy "sheet2" in both the Products.xlsx and Labels.xlsx workbooks and paste into the Sales 6.20.xlsb workbook under "sheet1". I then want to save the Sales 6.20.xlsb after getting the pasted data. I am struggling most with opening the file with a daily changing name. Thank you!

Comment: If Tuesday was the 26th of June, would your file be called "Sales 6.26.xlsb"? Would you be opening that file daily, so the file would be opened on Tuesday the 26th as it was called "Sales 6.26.xlsb"?

Comment: exactly. Wednesday I would open the same file (with updated data) renamed to Sales 6.27.xlsb

Answer (score 1):

This code uses 'Date' to retrieve today's date, then formats it as 'm.dd' which would return something like 6.28 and concatenates it with the filename.

Let me know if this does not work for you!

```
Sub open_workbook()

Dim wb As String
Dim filepath As String

filepath = "" 'your filepath ending in "\" here
wb = "Sales " & Format(Date, "m.dd") & ".xlsb" 'this code generates the filename
Workbooks.Open (filepath & wb) 'open the workbook

End Sub
```

Comment: That worked beautifully, thank you! The only thing is that when I want to close that file, I use: Workbooks("filepath & wb").Close and error '9' pops up highlighting this bit

Comment: That's because you have quotation marks around "filepath & wb" which is making Excel read them as text and not variables. Instead, you should use Workbooks(filepath & wb).Close . Please mark my answer as accepted if it worked for you. Thanks!

Comment: For some reason it is not working after taking away the quotation marks.